# Role Based Security for administrators for each school

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, security, database-design

I have a school management system where we manage 100 schools. We have administrators that help those schools. I am trying to setup security for different administrators.

```
For example:

Administrator 1 can have access to all 100 schools
Administrator 2 can only access 5 schools
Administrator 3 can only access 15 different schools
.
.
.
so on
```

I am trying to setup the security framework for the administrators. The easiest way is to have a AdminToSchool Database table where each admin will have a row for each school they have access to.

Possible Solution

```
Admin Id   School Id   AllowEdit  AllowDelete
 1            100S       1           1
 1            101S       1           1
 1            102S       1           1
 1            103S       1           1
 2            103S       1           1
 .
 .
 .
```

I am trying to think if there is a better way of doing this and use some role based security or any other possible way so it is easy to manage rather than keep adding rows to the table as we add or delete the access.

What is the best possible way to handle this?

Comment: While you could... you probably don't want to "roll your own" security.  Most database products have a security layer that you should lean into. The answer of what is "best" will rely heavily on a few questions.  Which database product you are using?  Is it MySQL?  SQL Server?  Do you have an existing identity management platform that handle storing usernames and passwords such as Active Directory?

Comment: From your username, we might be able to deduce that you are in the Microsoft ecosystem and using SQL Server.  For a primer on role-based access control give Phil Factor's [Schema-Based Access Control](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/schema-based-access-control-for-sql-server-databases/) a read.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one possible solution is to have a role table and then a `many to many associations` with your admin's tables, in that way you can get the roles associated with an admin in both directions (from a particular role and from an admin). This approach will allow you to have full control (role-based access control, of course, you need roles definitions for each school or at least in those cases where they have particularities), but be aware to `assign fewer privileges` needed for each admin to get their job done for example:

```
admin1 -> can_delete_schoolA, can_add_employees_schoolB
```

Where `admin1` is an element on the `admin's` table and `can_delete_schoolA`, `can_add_employees_schoolB` are elements on the roles table.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The design really depends on your use case.

Here is an example solution -

you can assign administrators to different groups as you need;

School access is assigned to groups;

All administrators in the group have same access permission assigned to the group;

```
Table groups:
group_id
group_name
description
...

Table group_members -- which member belongs to which group
group_id
admin_id
...

Table school_access -- which schools a group can access
group_id
school_id
allow_edit
allow_delete
```

Generally, school_access is pretty stable, given your rules for school access does not change frequently; So most times you only need to maintain group_members.